# Suppress echo of command invocation in makefile?

Tags: linux, unix, makefile, posix

I wrote a program for an assignment which is supposed to print its output to stdout. The assignment spec requires the creation of a Makefile which when invoked as `make run > outputFile` should run the program and write the output to a file, which has a SHA1 fingerprint identical to the one given in the spec.

My problem is that my makefile:

```
...
run:
     java myprogram
```

also prints the command which runs my program (e.g. java myprogram) to the output file, so that my file includes this extra line causing the fingerprint to be wrong.

Is there any way to execute a command without the command invocation echoing to the command line?

Comment: Great question, and great answers, though I would like to note that `make` is really intended to "make" files. So rather than `make run > outputFile`, a more appropriate use would, technically, be `make outputFile`, and the command would be `java myprogram > outputFile`. If you want it to _always_ run, then use `.PHONY`. I think `.SILENT` is a great answer if used that way because `make -v` would let you see the command used to generate it without affecting the output. The `@` prefix is a better answer if used the way you asked (with `> ouputFile`)

Comment: That said, I've used the phony usage more often in practice and tend to add `.PHONY: *` to the top of the file ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 452, accepted):

Add `@` to the beginning of command to tell gmake not to print the command being executed. Like this:

```
run:
     @java myprogram
```

As Oli suggested, this is a feature of Make and not of Bash.

On the other hand, Bash will never echo commands being executed unless you tell it to do so explicitly (i.e. with `-x` option).

Comment: +1.  But just to clear up the OP's confusion, it's perhaps worth clarifying that this is a feature of Make, not of Bash.

Comment: Is there a way of disabling all echos? Or of turning it off for a section, and back on later?

Comment: @Benubird `make -s` does that, and IMHO is a much better solution here anyway.  It was recently posted as a separate answer to this question.

Comment: this doesn't work for an if ... then statement :( any ideas?

Comment: IMO this is not good advice.  No recipe line that does anything more complex than an `echo` should ever be prefixed by `@`.  It makes debugging makefiles extremely difficult and time-consuming.  The right answer is to use the `.SILENT:` special target, which can be overridden via the command line when you do want to see the commands.

Comment: "-x" is an invalid option.. there is no such option as "-x"

Comment: if the command fails make still see that error right? @ suppresses output but not return code right?

Comment: @MSharq: `bash -xc 'echo hi'` prints "+ echo hi" on one line and "hi" on another

Answer (score 150):

Even simpler, use `make -s` (silent mode)!

Comment: Upvote: This should really be the accepted answer here.  Sprinkling your Makefile with `@` commands makes it hard to debug and adds a lot of clutter.

Comment: I agree this is the way to go - but notice, in the original problem description, I wouldn't be the one invoking make - my instructor would be. Thus, I would have no control over the flags passed in. I needed to control the output from within the makefile. Upvote for most practical solution in the real world though.

Comment: You can control this yourself, using the `.SILENT:` target.  See http://make.mad-scientist.net/managing-recipe-echoing/

Comment: Actually if you have warnings on like `-Wall` it still prints them. Of course why would you use `-s` if you want to see warnings too?

Comment: I disagree that this should be the accepted answer.  The person who asked wanted to suppress a single command not all commands.  This is still a useful piece of information but it suppresses all commands which is not what was asked for.

Answer (score 94):

You can also use [`.SILENT`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Special-Targets.html#Special-Targets)

```
hi:
    echo "Hola!"

.SILENT: run
run:
    java myprogram
```

In this case, `make hi` will print its `echo "Hola!"` recipe, 
but `make run` will not print `java myprogram`.

Answer (score 8):

The effect of preceding the command with an `@` can be extended to a section by extending the command using a trailing backslash on the line. If a `.PHONY` command is desired to suppress output one can begin the section with:

```sh
@printf "..."
```